# IndexOf and Contains ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that includes duplicates (sorta).

```
ArrayList al= new ArrayList();
al.Add("0","Detroit","Chicago","Week 2");
al.Add("1","Detroit","Baltimore","Week 3");
al.Add("2","Chicago","Boston","Week 2");
al.Add("3","Detroit","Tampa","Week 2");
```

I want to find out whether the ArrayList includes "Detroit"  and "Week 2".  Really, I want to avoid adding Line "3" to the ArrayList because a "Detroit" "Week 2" is already in the list.

My attempts at both IndexOf and Contains have proven unsatisfactory. 
Thanks

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, any reason you are not using `List<T>` ?

Comment: Indexes should be added as ints, not strings - eg `al.Add(0, "Detroit", "Chicago", "Week");`. This is one possible reason why your IndexOf might have failed. More information would be useful though :)

Comment: There is no ArrayList accepting 4 arguments. You´d better right your own datatype - with the four attributes and then create some instancens of this type and add it to your list.

Comment: a) non-compiling code, b) "It doesn't work" without details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve as you are not explaining it very clearly. But if you need to search in arrays that are added in a list and you do not mind using linq to make it a bit easier the following will compile and give you the outcome wanted

```
 List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
  string[] str1 = new string[] { "0", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Week 2" };
  string[] str2 = new string[] { "1", "Detroit", "Baltimore", "Week 3" };
  list.Add(str1);
  list.Add(str2);

  var t = list.Where(l => l.Contains("Chicago") || l.Contains("Week2")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class like:

```
class MyItem
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string OtherCityName { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }

    public MyItem(string No, string CityName, string OtherCityName, string Period)
    {
        this.No = No;
        this.CityName = CityName;
        this.OtherCityName = OtherCityName;
        this.Period = Period;
    }
}
```

Later you can add the input after checking if it doesn't exist in the list.

```
List<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>();
List<string[]> input = new List<string[]>();
input.Add(new[] { "0", "Detroit", "Chicago", "Week 2" });
input.Add(new[] { "1", "Detroit", "Baltimore", "Week 3" });
input.Add(new[] { "2", "Chicago", "Boston", "Week 2" });
input.Add(new[] { "3", "Detroit", "Tampa", "Week 2" });

foreach (var item in input)
{
    if (!list.Any(r => r.CityName == item[1] && r.Period == item[3]))
    {
        list.Add(new MyItem(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]));
    }
}
```

I am not sure how you are getting the input, that is why I created a `List<string[]>` for input. You can modify that part of code to your need. Also its better if you use `int` as data type for your `ID` or Serial Number.